# How do I create binary in XCode 5

Tags: ios5, binary, xcode5, .app

How can I create a binary in XCode 5? I want to find (or create) the .app file.

I tried the following:
Open project. Find folder with name Product.

But when I right click it, "open with finder" option is not enabled. So I am unable to select it.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to compile an xcodeproj to a .app?

Comment: @vcsjones Yes! I would like to create an executable file of my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure your debug is set to a device. Then Product > archive. However in order to send this app to someone you need to create a proper ad-hoc or distribution provisioning profile. Once you do that, you can email the .app file to your selected users.